Using past perfect in any clause
According to this thread I can use perfect anywhere with a very little difference in meaning. Is it true that when we use 'before' with the Past Perfect tense, the action in the past simple happens first? Do you agree with what Colin Fine says? Let me present my examples

I had arrived before you worked

I arrived before you had worked

I had arrived before you had worked


I think the only difference is that 1) means that I arrived before the work started and 2 and 3 before it was finished so it was already ongoing.

It seems you are deliberately choosing verbs like "cook" and "work" which are ongoing processes rather than verbs which have a defined completion that can serve as a point-in-time to be used with before.  Using such verbs makes your example sentences unidiomatic.  Change "worked" to "planted the tree" or "swallowed the goldfish" or "broke the window" or anything you like, but avoid such atelic verbs without any sort of aspectual modifier such as "began to work" or "stopped working".

Do you mean: Can we use past perfect in any clause?

What I see at the linked question is "Both of these sentences would sound equally good with a simple past in place of the past perfect. Furthermore, changing them in that way would have no effect on the sequence of events. What it would do ... would be to set a temporal focus at some later point in the past." This isn't the same as meaning "you can substitute perfect anywhere with very little change in meaning. The comment is about the specific sentences in that example, not necessarily applicable to all usages, and the "temporal focus" is a significant change in meaning.

What is true is that if we have any form of "I [verb X] before you [verb Y]," with any tenses, then X happens (or happened, or will happen) before Y. What isn't true is that all tenses are equally idiomatic for all situations, or that there is no overall change to the meaning of the sentence, since the order of events is not the only meaning.

First, as Tim notes, "worked" is not a great candidate for these examples because it's not really used for discrete events (which are needed to get the most mileage out of the pluperfect). If you replace it with "left" or some such verb, the examples are more intelligible.
Second, by saying "X happened before Y", you're also making explicit the meaning that is grammaticalized by the pluperfect and making it somewhat redundant. For example, consider this exchange:

— I didn't see you at the party.
— When did you get there?
— 8:30.
— Oh, I'd already left.

Here, "before you arrived" is understood because it's expressed by the use of the pluperfect itself.
These factors combine to make the examples sound awkwardly expressed at best.


I'd arrived before you left.

This situates my arrival before your leaving. The pluperfect is redundant because of the "before". Hence, we often substitute the preterite.

I arrived before you'd left.

Essentially the same logic means the preterite is fine here too.
Note that in both cases, the use of the pluperfect also suggests that there was an ongoing state defined by the discrete action. "I'd arrived" draws attention to a segment of time when I was present. "You'd left" draws attention to a segment of time when you were absent.

I'd arrived before you'd left.

For similar reasons, the only motivation to use such a structure would be if there were some third event that came after both of these ones, and we were trying to reconstruct the timeline to remember what the state of events was when that third event happened. Otherwise, we would just use the preterite.

No, it is not the case that one “can use perfect anywhere with a very little difference in meaning.” Consider for example that

I had finished making dinner when the guests arrived

could be spoken to describe the situation in which the making of dinner was completed, say, ten minutes before the guests’ arrival, whereas

I finished making dinner when the guests arrived

does not describe that same situation at all. Instead, that second example could be used to describe the situation in which part of the preparation of dinner was performed before the guests’ arrival, but the completion took place only after their arrival—perhaps the delay was intended so they could enjoy it hot at whatever (unknowable in advance) time they did arrive. This same (second) situation could also be described by the sentence

I finished making dinner when the guests had arrived,

though that is less idiomatic. A more natural version of this third example would start, “I only finished…” and replace when by after. Clearest would be

I waited to finish making dinner until the guests had arrived.


I. Using Before with Simple Past and Past Perfect.
The typical rule is to use the Past Perfect for the earlier action and the Simple Past for the later action. This applies well to situations where one action clearly finishes before another starts.
However, using  before + Past Perfect can imply an interrupted or unfinished action, rather than a fully completed one.
Consider these examples (OP's cannot explain the concept):

The guest had arrived before she finished cooking..
Here, the Past Perfect shows that the arrival happened before cooking was fully done.
The guest arrived before she had finished cooking..
In this sentence, before + Past Perfect suggests that cooking was interrupted by the guest’s arrival and was incomplete.

II. Explanation: Past Perfect for Interrupted or Incomplete Action

Before can pair with either the Simple Past or the Past Perfect. If the action after before is a new, completed action, use Simple Past. If the action was ongoing or incomplete, use Past Perfect.
.
Compare these examples:
Jane had read a lot about elephants before she went to the zoo..
This implies that Jane finished reading before going to the zoo..
.
Jane went to the zoo before she had finished reading her new book about elephants..
Here, Jane’s reading was incomplete when she went to the zoo..
.
Before + Past Perfect

